# Using Thread.Sleep when calling a event, but doesn't work?(C#)

Tags: c#, multithreading

everyone:
I recently using **《Illustrated C# 2010》**for learning csharp, and I just come to the 16th Chapter "Event". **There is a sample in it, and I run the original code but get different result.** I'm really confused! Below is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace EventSample1
{
    public class MyTimerClass
    {
        public event EventHandler MyElapsed; 
        private void OnOneSecond(object source, EventArgs args)
        {
            if(MyElapsed != null)
                MyElapsed(source, args);
        }
        //----
        private System.Timers.Timer MyPrivateTimer; 
        public MyTimerClass()
        {
            MyPrivateTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(); 
            MyPrivateTimer.Elapsed += OnOneSecond; 
            MyPrivateTimer.Interval = 1000;               
            MyPrivateTimer.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
    //----
    class classA
    {
        public void TimerHandlerA(object source, EventArgs args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("class A handler called!");
        }
    }
    class classB
    {
        public static void TimerHandlerB(object source, EventArgs args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("class B handler called!");
        }
    }
    //-----
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            classA ca = new classA();
            MyTimerClass mc = new MyTimerClass();
            //----
            mc.MyElapsed += ca.TimerHandlerA;
            mc.MyElapsed += classB.TimerHandlerB;
            //----
            Thread.Sleep(2250);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**The book said that we'll get TimerHandler A and B both performed twice while the thread sleeping for 2.25s'.** And there should be 4lines on the screen.
Like this:

```
>>class A handler called!
>>class B handler called!
>>class A handler called!
>>class B handler called!
```

**But after I run the codes, TimerHandler A and B is called like forever, more than 2 times.** Like this:

```
>>class A handler called!
>>class B handler called!
>>class A handler called!
>>class B handler called!
>>class A handler called!
>>class B handler called!
>>class A handler called!
>>class B handler called!
......
```

I guess there's something wrong in using `thread.sleep`, but I haven't learned anything about threads in C#...And in the book, there are no explain on why we should use `thread.sleep`, and why using it will control the event to perform only twice.

Could someone explain? Is this a mistake in this book? Or there is anything wrong with me?
I use vs2010 on XP.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Program has `Console.ReadLine()` which will wait forever until you hit the Return key. While it is waiting the Timers are still running and will therefore fire the Events. In this scenario, the `Thread.Sleep` is meaningless.

I expect the intention of the author was to prevent the Console app from exiting and vanishing before you saw the results.

If you comment out the `ReadLine()`, the program will behave as described in the book but the app will exit and disappear immediately after 2.25 seconds, so keep a close eye on the screen to see the effect.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Your answer is very clear! But I still have some questions referring to this code example, and reposted more details in anther question......Can you go there and have a look? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38318677/about-threads-being-used-in-the-event-calling-in-c-sharp?noredirect=1#comment64056069_38318677) @phil-blackburn